# Generate mean of select rows in a column with R

Tags: r

Apologies if this has been asked before, but other simliar questions I couldnt get to work with my data frame. And if it's not obvious Im quite new at coding in genreal.

A simplified version of my data.frame

| Sex | Age | X |
**-----------------**
| F   | One | 1 |
| F   | One | 2 |
| F   | Two | 1 |
| F   | Two | 2 |
| M   | One | 1 |
| M   | One | 2 |
| M   | Two | 1 |
| M   | Two | 2 |

And Im trying to produce a seperate mean of the X column for the F one, F two, M one and M two, such as the table below.

| Sex | Age | X |
**-----------------**
| F   | One | mean |
| F   | Two | mean |
| M   | One | mean |
| M   | Two | mean |

Any help or direction on where to look would be very helpful.
Thanks.

Comment: You can use `dplyr` like this: `df %>% group_by (Sex, Age) %>% summarise(Mean = mean(X))`

Comment: Or `aggregate(X~Sex + Age, df, mean, na.rm = TRUE)` in base R.